# why my python or logic returning the print statement?

Tags: python

I start learning python. Here is my logic

```
A = 123
B = 124

if 124 != A or B:
   #do something
   print("value doesn't match")
```

so above statement shouldn't return print because value 124 ==  B but why I am getting the print statement? I am not understanding this. I know it's vey silly question but as a beginner I am not understanding this concept. please help me to understand why my or logic return print where I already have matching value.

if I try:

```
if B != 124:
   #do something
   print("value doesn't match")
```

then it's working but why not working `A or B` together ?

Comment: The python keyword ```or ```takes precedence after ```!=```. The statement evaluates to ```(124 != A) or (B)``` rather than ```(124 != A) or (124 != B)``` . In python all numbers except 0 is True, so both ```124 != A``` and ```B``` return True.

Comment: @MT756 the issue isn't really *precedence* in this case, the issue is that the `!=` doesn't automatically distribute over the `or` like it does in natural language.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga also tried `(124 != A) or (124 != B) `  but it's returning print statement and don't know why

Comment: I think you want `and`

Answer (score 0):

`if 124 != A or B:`  this will check like this.

It's evaluated separately between `or.

`124 != A` will give you `True` and `B` itself also gives you `True`.

```
In [1]: if 124 != A:
     ...:     print("value doesn't match")
     ...: 
# value doesn't match

In [2]: if B:
     ...:     print("value doesn't match")
     ...: 
# value doesn't match
```

**If something not understanding in python take step by step and execute it in the python interpreter.**

For the together check you need to write like this,

```
if 123 != A or 124 != B:
    print("value doesn't match")
```

Comment: I try this 1=`if 124 != A or 124 != B:` but still now getting print statement

Comment: yeah because the value of A is `123`